# How to change default “sort by” to “type”

Tags: pantheon-files, default

How to change default “sort by” to “type”?

I want to change in all subfolders.
I use ubuntu with pantheon theme, default isn't nautilus.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right click on an empty space into pantheon-files application and you will have some sort options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the *default* sort order I am afraid.  You can only change the order of individual folders using the method given in the previous order. If you want this feature to be implemented you could raise an issue at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues.

There is an argument, perhaps, that when you change the sort order of a folder then the sort order of its subfolders should change as well.